# Use CodeIgniter constant variable to in language file

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, I'm working with multi-language functionality. where I have declared my project name as a CONSTANT variable in the
`application/config/constant.php`

```php
<?php

define('COMPANY', 'CPMG');
```

My statement should be printed like this "Notify CPMG/ Remarketing of Thailand if personal property is not accessible"

So I have to define the message in the `application/language/english/english_lang.php`

```php
$lang['note'] = 'Notify CPMG/ Remarketing of Thailand if personal property is not accessible;
```

Now, I want to use my constant variable in the multi-language string where it replaces the company name with my constant value, for me that is ***CPMG***

It's possible to use a constant variable in language files?

Comment: Is the question "how to nest a constant in a string" OR have you actually tried to nest it and it did not work ?

Comment: It's the question that how will I do that? I have tried in this way but it's not working. @NoahBoegli

Comment: Given the fact that your constant is COMPANY, it should be nested like that: `$str = 'a string '.COMPANY.' with a nested constant';`
If you have tried that, what is the output or the error ?

Comment: Terminology note: there is no such thing as a "constant variable" - a "variable" is called that because its value can *vary* as the program runs; a "constant" is the opposite, its value never changes. Also note that this question isn't specific to Laravel, just PHP general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function as below:

```
$lang['note'] = 'Notify %s/ Remarketing of Thailand if personal property is not accessible';
```

Use the string as follows:
`echo sprintf($this->lang->line('note'),COMPANY);`